# Not able to fetch data in react/next js although able to console log it

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, console.log

I am using Next Js (React Js) to develop my Web app here, I have also used graphql to get my data from database I am also getting it but not able to render it on screen. What should I do!

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import moment from 'moment'

import {getRecentPosts , getSimilarPosts} from '../../services'

const PostWidget = ({categories , slug}) => {

    const [relatedPosts, setRelatedPosts] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(slug){
            getSimilarPosts(categories, slug).then((result) => setRelatedPosts(result))
        }
        else{
            getRecentPosts().then((result) => setRelatedPosts(result))
        }
       
    }, [slug])
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>
                {slug ? "Related Posts" : "Recent Posts"}
            </h3>
            {relatedPosts.map((post) =>{
                <div key={post.slug}>
                    <div className="image">
                        <img 
                        src={post.featuredImage.url} 
                        alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <p>{moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}</p>
                        <h3>{post.title.toString()}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PostWidget
```

When I `console.log(relatedPosts)` this I am able to get the data in json format but when I try to use it like above I am not getting the post information and am not able to show my data in my web page

Comment: fix the code on your question and try the service with a postman to verify if it is working

Comment: @JRichardsz I have tried it it's not working I am not able to show to data on the screen although able to log it to the console

Comment: If the http service that returns you the related post don't work, with react it won't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{relatedPosts.map((post) => (
                <div key={post.slug}>
                    <div className="image">
                        <img 
                        src={post.featuredImage.url} 
                        alt="" 
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="content">
                        <p>{moment(post.createdAt).format('MMM DD, YYYY')}</p>
                        <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
```

Because I inserted a {curly bracket} instead of a (paranthesis):
`(post)=>{ code/JSX } ❌` 
We can correct this in two ways :
`(post)=>{ return ( code/JSX )} ✔`
**or**
`(post)=>( code/ JSX(react/next) ) ✔`